Chrome extension: Run a function for specific website context?
Theres a specific website that has certain function that I'd like my Chrome extension to run whenever the page is active. Lets call this website website1 (Main context)
Website1 has a function called enable() that I'd like to run:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>
  
<script>
  function enable(){
    /// run some code
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>

Now to my understanding injecting a contentScript from my Chrome extension will run JS in its own sort of context and not the main context for website1. So calling  website1.enable() from the contentscript actually results in the below error for me:
contentScript.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: website1

How can I call website1.enable() in it's context from my chrome extension?
Current solution
I have been looking at this question
Simply adding "world": "MAIN", to my contentscript in combination with mutation observer seems to work. But, curious to know what others think about this approach.

This is the correct method for Chrome. In Firefox you can use wrappedJSObject instead.
